# Python - Javascript encrypt function for a known decrypt function

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, cryptography

I found a streaming website that encrypts the iframe code with an interesting Javascript function. On the webpage is visible the decrypt function (obviously) but not the encryption one. This is the function:

```
function base64_decode(data) {
    var b64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
        ac = 0,
        dec = '',
        tmp_arr = [];
    if (!data) {
        return data;
    }
    data += '';
    do {
        h1 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h2 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h3 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h4 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;
        o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
        o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
        o3 = bits & 0xff;
        if (h3 == 64) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
        } else if (h4 == 64) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
        } else {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
        }
    } while (i < data.length);
    dec = tmp_arr.join('');
    return dec.replace(/\0+$/, '');
}

function ord(string) {
    var str = string + '',
        code = str.charCodeAt(0);
    if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) {
        var hi = code;
        if (str.length === 1) {
            return code;
        }
        var low = str.charCodeAt(1);
        return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
    }
    if (0xDC00 <= code && code <= 0xDFFF) {
        return code;
    }
    return code;
}

function decrypt(sData, sKey) {
    var sResult = "";
    sData = base64_decode(sData);
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sData.length; i++) {
        var sChar = sData.substr(i, 1);
        var sKeyChar = sKey.substr(i % sKey.length - 1, 1);
        sChar = Math.floor(ord(sChar) - ord(sKeyChar));
        sChar = String.fromCharCode(sChar);
        sResult = sResult + sChar;
    }
    return sResult;
}
```

So this code:

```
decrypt('s+Dd6djk3Jfq6dq0md/r6+fqsaam5ufc5ePm2Nul2uam3OTZ3Numy83Zw87aqazMvbimmZfq2unm4+Pg5d60meXmmZfd6djk3Nnm6dvc6bSZp5mX7uDb69+0mainp5yZl9/c4N7f67SZqKennJmX2OPj5u7d7OPj6trp3NzltJnr6ezcmZfu3Nni4OvY4+Pm7t3s4+Pq2unc3OW0mevp7NyZl+Tm8djj4+bu3ezj4+ra6dzc5bSZ6+ns3Jm1s6bg3enY5Ny1', 'w')
```

will return:

```
<iframe src="https://openload.co/embed/TVbLWc25UFA/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

I translated the decrypt function in Python with `math` and `base64` modules and it works well, but now I need the encrypt function (in Python) that starting from a string outputs encrypted string + key. Is it some kind of known encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bad implementation of the Vigenère cipher, without the modulus as the resulting `sChar` may have higher values. It simply adds the value of a key character to each plain character, reusing the key if it is depleted. It will mainly function as something to confuse virus-scanners or packet-inspecting firewalls as the encryption itself is of course completely insecure. It won't have a name (and no self-respecting cryptographer will lend his name for it either).

There seems to be a bug in the code here:

```
sKey.substr(i % sKey.length - 1, 1);
```

I'm not sure why the `- 1` is required or how this plays out in practice (this is why languages and API's should be strict in what is acceptable).

`ord` seems to have been implemented to avoid issues with 16-bit Unicode characters.

`base64_decode` simply implements base 64 decoding, nothing to see there.